# Distribution of residual errors of RNNs

Tags: normal-distribution, residuals, recurrent-neural-network

I have developed four RNNs (LSTM, GRU, BiLSTM and BiGRU). All of these models give residual errors with non-normal distribution. Is this acceptable? I know that for linear regression problems, we need residuals with normal distribution. But what about RNNs?